# What percentage of damage is restored as health to the wielder?

Tags: borderlands-2

[The Borderlands Wiki article on the Creamer unique rocket launcher weapon](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Creamer) states that one of [the weapon's special effects](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Creamer#Special_Weapon_Effects) is "Inflicted damage restores health to the weapon's wielder." However, unlike the other Miss Moxxi's weapons, the article doesn't state how much percentage of damage is restored to the wielder

What percentage of damage is restored as health from Creamer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this post [in the borderlands wiki,](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Rubi) all of Moxxi's weapons return 2% of damage back as health. The Rubi is much higher (12%), in case you were wondering.

Comment: Through tests I've gotten between 1.9% and 2.3% so around 2 percent would be right for the Creamer

Comment: And Grog Nozzle is 65%. (Rubi 12.5)